# Converting enum to enum not working when are not in same order

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Working on a project where they have lots of enums and lots of duplicated objects across multiple dlls.
 A mess but lets move on.

I have  this extension method that works when converting an Enum to Enum that have the same position in the enum
 however it fails if the name is the same but the position of the enum is different

How can Improve my code so that it gets the correct enum based on name match regardless where is located in the enum

Thanks

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ToEnum_convert_returnsCorrectEnum()
        {
            const CategoryA categoryALawyer = CategoryA.Lawyer;
            var result = categoryALawyer.ToEnum<CategoryB>();

            Assert.AreEqual(CategoryA.Lawyer.ToString(),result.ToString());
        }
    }


    namespace Utilities
    {
        public enum CategoryA
        {
            Lawyer,
            Developer,
            Manager,
            Employee,
            Director,

        }

        public enum CategoryB
        {
            Director,
            Manager,
            Developer,
            Employee,
            Lawyer
        }

        public static class EnumExtensions
        {
            public static T ToEnum<T>(this Enum value)
            {
                return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), value);
            }               
        }
    }
```

## EDIT

Some dlls I have no control over so I cannot change enum order

Comment: If you order the names differently, the names will correspond to different values unless you assign them manually. This is basically how enums work, and is by design.

Comment: This behavior isn't that surprising when you think about it.  Remember you can explicitly convert Enum value to Ints and back.

Comment: I didn't know that this compiles `Director,`(in `CategoryA`).

Comment: I dont have controls of some dlls so I have not control of order.Is there a way I can parse all the names etc...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It compiles. That's allowed

Comment: If you have too many objects to be matched then it is better to use AutoMapper to map these objects.

Comment: You would need to get the *name* associated with the current enum value, and then use `Enum.(Try)Parse` using the other enum. But multiple names can be associated with a single value, so no guarantee you'll find the "correct" name from enum A. (@dbaseman's answer seem to assume 1-1 between name and value)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The relevant thing here seems to be the name. The name has to be unique in an enum, so it is guaranteed that he will find the correct value.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - the names have to be unique - but if enum A has two names associated with value 1, there's no guarantee of which name will be returned by e.g. ToString.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Is that really the case? Can you show some evidence of this? I couldn't reproduce it with [a simple empiric test](http://pastebin.com/7Gn7HqKz).

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - [Enum.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx): "If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The important point is "**based on its underlying value**". This is not the case here.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - in your paste-bin sample, change the lines in Main referring to Lawyer to use UpdateStatus instead (leave the enum definition alone) and you'll get 10000000 wrongs.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Wow, indeed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
T val;
if (Enum.TryParse<T>(value.ToString(), out val))
    return val;
else return default(T);
```

Edit: changed "Parse" to the correct "TryParse".  Also, the TryParse method has an overload to make it case-insensitive if you want:

```
Enum.TryParse<T>(value.ToString(), true, out val)
```